# Tag merge request: [mediaelement] and [mediaelement.js]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I suggest to merge [mediaelement](/questions/tagged/mediaelement) (161 questions) with [mediaelement.js](/questions/tagged/mediaelement.js) (65 questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the merge proposal. Those tags can mean different things: [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) is an HTML5 video player and [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) is a .NET audio/video playback control. They are named in a similar way and perform a similar function, but questions about one are not the same as questions about the other.

Comment: +1, particularly as the top questions in that tag (as linked by the OP) are about WPF